# Convert a [String] list to a [Double] list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function to convert a list of String (read from a CSV file) to a list of Doubles. It gives me an error in the 3rd line.

```
stringToDouble :: [String] -> [Double]
stringToDouble [] = error "empty list"
stringToDouble [x] = read x :: Double -- the `read` gives me an error
stringToDouble (x:xs) = stringToDouble xs
```

Is it because I'm not putting the converted Double in a list which needs to be returned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error arises from the fact that `read x` is of type `Double`, not `[Double]`, but as it stands your function will not work as intended even with that fix.

Let's take your function and put it into words: "Take the front element of a list of strings, read it as a double, and then do the same to the rest of the list". Now let's look at your function:

```
stringToDouble :: [String] -> [Double]
stringToDouble [] = error "empty list"
stringToDouble [x] = read x :: Double -- Error
stringToDouble (x:xs) = stringToDouble xs
```

Now let's apply the fix to it. Also, there's no reason to error on the empty list; just yield and empty list of doubles:

```
stringToDouble :: [String] -> [Double]
stringToDouble [] = []
stringToDouble [x] = [read x :: Double] -- Put the single value into a list
stringToDouble (x:xs) = stringToDouble xs
```

The problem lies in the recursive step. Calling `stringToDouble` on a list is the same as calling `stringToDouble` on the tail of the list. The first element is simply discarded. You want to convert the head and put it back on the list.

```
stringToDouble :: [String] -> [Double]
stringToDouble [] = []
stringToDouble [x] = [read x :: Double] -- Put the single value into a list
stringToDouble (x:xs) = (read x :: Double) : stringToDouble xs
```

Where `(:)` is the operator used to attach an element to the front of the list. And with that, the middle line isn't even needed, since the recursive step will handle the conversion and the empty list step will handle the stop condition.

```
stringToDouble :: [String] -> [Double]
stringToDouble [] = []
stringToDouble (x:xs) = (read x :: Double) : stringToDouble xs
```

Now, realistically, you could *probably* remove the `:: Double` portion and Haskell would figure out what you meant with the type constraint of the function, but it won't hurt and sometimes it helps readability to leave it in.

Comment: thanks very much for the explenation. What do you suggest if I have a list like this `["a","1.2"]`.. how do I only use the numbers and not the words so that "a" will be ignored? By regex maybe?

Comment: What do you mean "ignored"? What do you want to happen to non-numerals? You can't have a heterogeneous list in Haskell, so you can't have e.g. ["a", 1.2], as that doesn't have a valid type.

Comment: If the intent is to ignore values which can't be read, then define `readMaybe x = case reads x of { [(y, "")] -> Just y; _ -> Nothing }` and `stringToDouble = catMaybes . map readMaybe`

Answer (score 1):

You're right - `read x :: Double` is of type `Double`, while the return type of the function is of type `[Double]` (meaning "a list of `Double`").

Something like this:

```
stringToDouble [x] = [read x :: Double]
```

should work.

Note that if you're trying to convert each element of the list independently, then you should write your function using `map` instead of using explicit recursion. If `f` is of type `String -> Double`, then `map f` will be a function of type `[String] -> [Double]`.

Comment: If I do this, it only prints the first element. `stringToDouble (x:xs) = stringToDouble xs` does not get executed

Comment: Your current function only calls `read` on the last element of a list: if a list has more than one items, it ignores the first one. Maybe you meant something like `stringToDouble (x:xs) = read x : stringToDouble xs` in the third case?

Comment: @letsjak It does get executed (for lists containing more than one element), but all it does is recurse on the tail.